# How effective is automatic fixing of RAW files?

Tags: software, post-processing, raw, workflow

I was wondering if there is any good software for automatic fixing of RAW files, that is, a basic initial fix of exposure, vibrance, sharpening and NR.
I heard about Athentech. However, I could not find too many reviews.

What is your opinion about it, and which other alternatives are worth considering (again, I'm looking for something that quickly performs an initial fix to save time, and later personalize the photo myself)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe Camera Raw (used by Photoshop) has an one-click [Auto levels button](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop//10.0/help.html?content=WS8F52A240-D2DA-4a24-AF39-630548509498.html) that will adjust

- exposure
- contrast
- highlights and shadows
- whites
- blacks

Lighroom has [Auto-tone](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1930485&seqNum=5) presets that do the same thing.

[Raw Therapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/) (open source) has an [Auto Levels](http://rawtherapee.com/blog/rawtherapee-4.0.7-released) adjustment which covers:

- Exposure compensation
- Highlight recovery amount & threshold
- Black level & shadow compression
- RGB brightness
- RGB contrast

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) has an [Auto](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-levels.html) button under Levels to adjust black/white levels, and some other [Auto](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-colors-auto-menu.html) options that include white balance and contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Lightroom can do automated actions on import. You can [create your own presets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS2A36C507-E076-4b14-AAC3-87852595D175.html) that apply when you import images into the database. Those can also include the automatic Exposure and other fixes.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Athentech Perfectly Clear is available as a LR plugin.